# Set checkbox inside NSTableView to "YES"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` with a checkbox column and an `NSArrayController`.

The `NSTableView` is bound to the `NSArrayController` to show its content. 
The checkbox column is bound to `imgArrayController.arrangedObjects.check1`. When the program starts the array is empty. I add values using the arrayController in a loop this way:

```
    [imgArrayController addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [NSImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName]], @"image", 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName], @"filename", 
        @"YES", @"check1", 
        nil]];
```

The correct number of rows are added, however I am getting an error when it tries to set checkbox to YES. This is the error I get:

```
2013-02-03 19:11:46.357 Stockuploader[561:303] Error setting value for key path check1 of object {
} (from bound object <NSTableColumn: 0x100152280>   identifier: check1): [<__NSDictionaryI 0x10010c190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key check1.
```

Could somebody please help me to understand what I am doing wrong? The rows appear inside the table but they are all empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.  Also try using `[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]` instead of `@"YES"` (which is a string, not a boolean).

EDIT:

In a cell-based `NSTableView` you would need to bind the *column* (not the cell itself) to the arrayController with a Controller Key of arrangedObjects and a Model Key Path of `check1`.

In a view-based `NSTableView` you would need to bind the *checkbox control* to the Table Cell View with a Model Key Path of `objectValue.check1`.

Comment: Is this NSTableView view-based or cell-based?

Comment: i am a beginner, but AFAIK its viewbased.

Comment: If you just added it in IB and never changed anything it's cell-based. Added some info to my answer that might be helpful.

Comment: ok thanks for explaining! :) its cell based then, and i have bound the column to the arraycontroller, and typed check1 as model key path. but its not checking the box. i am alo calling the reloaddata method.

Comment: It's hard to say what else could be wrong. Typically you wont need to call `-reloadData` when using bindings.

Comment: i have to go out now, will post some screenshots Tomorrow! thank you for your help! :)

Comment: sorry if i didnt reply! all working! thanks for your solution!